# mat-form-field in mat-list-item overlapping

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing an . user interface for the firebase login. For that i am using `angular material`.

For easier input correction on the user side i want to implement `mat-hint`s for the user to show an error whenever the user typed something that was not expected.

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Log into your existing account</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <h3 mat-subheader>Profile</h3>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>alternate_email</mat-icon>
        <mat-form-field mat-line class="width-100">
          <input matInput placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" [formControl]="emailFormControl"
            [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
          <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Please enter a valid email address
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Email is <strong>required</strong>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>security</mat-icon>
        <mat-form-field mat-line class="width-100">
          <input matInput #passwordtest type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" />
          <mat-hint align="end" *ngIf="passwordtest.value.length < 6">{{passwordtest.value.length}} / 6 or more</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="login(email, password)">Login</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

However it seems that the `mat-form-field` with `mat-hint`s and placeholders is not designed to work within an `mat-list-item`, because the result looks like this.

[image]

if i remove the `mat-list-item` (and the little icon in front of the `mat-form-field`) then the hints and placeholders are not overlapping.

[image]

As you can see, the result is not pretty as well because the subheader is misaligned with the form field. Additionally, i think that the first option (with the overlapping) looks better because of the little icons.

I'm wondering what my options are in this situation because i don't want to break the material design by adding additional margins or paddings. However, i guess that this is intended behaviour and that i am doing something wrong.

**How can i design this user interface in a way that the input fields with hints and placeholders are not overlapping?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the height of `.mat-list-item` using `!important` like so:

```
.mat-list-item {
    height: 80px !important; /** experiment with height **/
}
```

A better way to do it would be to provide styling with higher specificity (i.e. add an extra class to each `list-item` with your styling).

```
.custom-class .mat-list-item {
    height: 80px;
}
```

The alternative is to add padding to the left of `mat-form-field` to match the padding of the header.

Comment: for all that dont want to figure out the value themselves you can use `.mat-list-item { height: auto !important; }` as well

Answer (score 4):

```
<mat-list-item style="height:auto" *ngFor="let item of itemList"> ..
```

height:auto also worked for me. Without this, I observed overlapping texts. If auto works, it is better than fixing the pixel value.